# Node, Nuxt, MongoDB, nuxt/auth - How to get user _id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, nuxt.js

I'm building an app with Node/Nuxt and try to log in user with nuxt/auth. Signup and Login works fine. But if I try to get the own user profile, I don't have an idea how to do it dynamically.

Here is my node route of /GET User.
And here I need your help. In `const userId = x` I pasted the User _id manually, but I need it of course dynamically. Something like `const userId = req.user`

```
router.get('/auth/user', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userId = '5f6c6f1d312bc5695641b6c2';
    console.log(userId);
    const foundUser = await User.findById(userId);
    if (!foundUser) return next(new Error('User does not exist'));
    res.status(200).json({
      data: foundUser,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

[SCREENSHOT: Here is the userID I which I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxAbm.png)

Here is my auth strategie in nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/auth/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'accessToken',
          },
          logout: { url: '/api/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/api/auth/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false },
        },
        tokenType: '',
      },
    },

  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a Node way of doing things than a Nuxt way of doing things, but you want to use a route paramater.

```js
router.get('/auth/user/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.params.id;
    console.log(userId);
    const foundUser = await User.findById(userId);
    if (!foundUser) return next(new Error('User does not exist'));
    res.status(200).json({
      data: foundUser,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Another way to do this would be to use Nuxt's [Vuex store](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/) to create a state object into which you save the user ID and the user's profile data so that it can be invoked as-needed throughout your project.

`store/index.js`:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  userId: null,
  userProfile: null
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_USER_ID(state, payload) {
    state.userId = payload
  },
  SET_USER_PROFILE(state, payload) {
    state.userProfile = payload
  }
}

export const actions = {
  setUserId({ commit }, payload) {
    commit('SET_USER_ID', payload)
  },
  setUserProfile({ commit }), payload {
    commit('SET_USER_PROFILE', payload)
  }
}
```

`user.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>The user's id is {{ userid }}.</div>
    <div>The user's profile is: {{ profile }}.</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions} from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
     ...mapState([userId, userProfile])
  },
  async mounted() {
    const id = (await yourLoginFunction()).user.id
    this.setUserId(id)
    
    const profile = (await yourProfileLoader(id)).user.profileData
    this.setUserProfile(profile)
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([setUserId, setProfile])
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But, I don't need to use a parameter. I need to put the ID from the response somehow. (See --> Screenshot). Unfortunately, I still don't have the ID in the url, that I could use the id from param.

Comment: That being the case, what you probably want to do instead is to use the built-in Vuex store. I'll update my answer.